# How does one create a Cross-Reference relating formula names to the Cells or programs that use them

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping that someone has a program that creates a cross reference for Names and Cells like a compiler cross reference that tells which statements use what labels. I actually want both. I would like to produce a document that tells which cells and which Visual Basic for Applications  programs (even which statements if the statements are numbered) use names that are in the formula Names collection.

It usually amounts to parsing and sorting. I think I can do it, but would like to use existing code, if there is such a thing.

Anybody out there interested?

Comment: You'd need a VBA parser to do that. It's not an easy exercise. Nonetheless, asking for code like this is off-topic on SO. It's also a very broad question. You really should tackle this yourself and come back when you get stuck.

Comment: `Range(SomeFunction() & "22")` not so simple to parse...